# What's the best way to seal around this faucet?

Tags: sealing, siding

This faucet is not hooked up to a live pipe, but it still sticks out the side of my 110 year old house. The siding is fiber cement containing asbestos (and no, I'm not worried about working with it).

What's the best way to seal it up so water can't get in the house? There is some expanding foam insulation inside the house around the pipe where it leaves the house already.

[faucet http://plk.webimages.s3.amazonaws.com/faucet.JPG](http://plk.webimages.s3.amazonaws.com/faucet.JPG)

Comment: Have you considered removing the faucet so you could patch it permanently?  Especially since it is not active.

Comment: Well, it's the only faucet I have outside, so I expect to want to hook it up someday. But, yes, I have.

Comment: If you hook it up you'll likely want to replace the faucet anyway - may as well yank the old ugly until you buy a new pretty. :)

Comment: I ended up replacing the entire thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like clear silicone caulk for this kind of job.

It will remain flexible after curing, so if the pipe gets bumped or moved around it won't break or crack like expanding foam.  And the clear caulk won't stand out since it cures to a translucent light grey color which is similar to the siding.